# Prisma client becomes undefined after n number of successful requests

Tags: node.js, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

We use Prisma with ApolloGraphQL, and make it available through the context. We are using the following versions:

```
@prisma/client: ^3.5.0 (dev-dep)
@prisma: ^3.5.0
```

It *seems* that after a specific rawQuery, the client falls over, and all subsequent requests fail with `"cannot read property 'tableName' of undefined"`. This is in reference specifically to all prisma.[tableName].[operation] usages.

When we `console.log` the prisma client within the same resolver, it exists, but after the unknown event it is undefined.

I have ensured that the schema file is up-to-date with our database having run a `prisma pull db` + `prisma generate`.

I have also verified that the type being coerced by the `$rawQuery` is exactly the same as the results being returned (this is in reference to the specific rawQuery mentioned above).

In the case of this particular rawQuery, we import Prisma directly from the Prisma file where it is defined as it is a service used in multiple resolvers. The resolvers themselves use the Prisma client provided in the context - could this be a potential cause?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Tasin from the Prisma team here. This is really strange. Would you please consider creating a [new bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) in the Prisma repository, _along with a reproduction_. That would really help us get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hey Tasin, I actually found the root cause today. One of our subscriptions wasn't returning all of the data that it expected, and Apollo then tried to fetch the missing fields. Strange thing is that when that request to our API happens, our entire context gets removed (including the prisma client). I don't believe it is a Prisma issue because of this.

Thanks for the response though, love your product

Comment: Really happy to hear you're enjoying Prisma and that the problem was solved :D. Btw, we're quite active in responding to people's issues on [slack](https://slack.prisma.io/) as well, I would definitely suggest joining.